# Displaying milliseconds when retrieving from DB

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

in my db i have:

```
2011-01-28 12:03:46.223
```

when displaying on .aspx page,

```
<%# Eval("ModifiedDateTime") == null ? "&nbsp;" : Eval("ModifiedDateTime")%>
```

it displays on the grid like this:

```
12/2/2010 8:43:18 AM
```

how do I format it like the default format shown when I query my db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use an appropriate [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), something more like this:

```
  (new Date(Eval("ModifiedDateTime")))).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.FFF")
```

This replaces the final clause in your if/else statement. Note that it doesn't really make sense to say "I want to display whatever is in your db" - you are really asking "how do I format it like the default format shown when I query my db".

Check the link for the exact syntax you want, but what I've given should do.